# nginx redirects to the same url

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-config

I configured nginx as the following code

```
ssl_certificate  example.crt;
ssl_certificate_key example.key;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 200 hello;
}
```

and I expect to get `200` for `curl -I https://example.com` but it gives me `301`

```
curl -I http://example.com => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
location===https://example.com

curl -I https://example.com => HTTP/2 301
location===https://example.com

curl -I https://example.com/asdasd => HTTP/2 301  
location===https://example.com/asdasd
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: The server configuration is not consistent with the results you are seeing. View the configuration using `nginx -T`. Do you have anything in front of the server and have you restarted Nginx since changing the configuration? Check the access logs to ensure that this server is the one that's responding.

Comment: I haven't changed nginx.conf, yes I restart it whenever I change the config, and access.log is ok, I noticed that it always uses the first server block configuration even for https requests

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't make sense - there must be something in front of this `server` block that is terminating the https connection - like cloudflare.

Comment: but the cloudflarer is OK as well, Universal SSL Status : Active Certificate

Comment: What happens for https requests? how `https://example.com/asdasd` changes to `https://example.com/asdasd`?

Comment: Cloudflare will proxy HTTPS requests to your first `server` block. That's its purpose.

Comment: Finally I found a setting in cloudflare to redirect http request to https, and removed redirect in nginx. Thanks a lot.